# Is there a way to determine if a byte-stream is built using protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Just wondering if there's some sort of special starting characters in a byte stream so I can detect that it is a protobuf message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The [encoding format](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/) doesn't have anything like that. Including such a thing would have been too much overhead for small messages, and too unreliable to be useful.